# Explode() is giving server error, page can't load

Tags: php, arrays, explode, fread

```
<?php
$myFile = "file.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
print_r ($theData);
fclose($fh)
?>
```

This is my current code, which has successfully read my file and printed the data to the screen. However now when I try to explode the data I just get a sever error and the page doesn't load at all, the only error message I get is `page may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly` and I don't understand why it isn't working.

I am trying to put

```
$my_array = explode("/n", $theData);
```

after the data has been read, and before it is printed, but every time I add it the page gives up, but when I take it out the page loads again fine.
I need to be able to put in a foreach loop to explode the data and print it out one line at a time (it's an email directory) but I don't understand why it's not working.

```
$myFile = "file.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
$assoc_array = array()
$my_array = explode("\n", $theData);
foreach($my_array as $line)
{
    $tmp = explode(" ", $line);
    $assoc_array[$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1];
}
fclose($fh)
$mail = $assoc_array;
```

I have tried this code, which I found while doing the original research for how to read from .txt file to array, but it still throws up the server error problem.

Could someone explain where I'm going wrong?

---

In the end the code I've used is:

```
<?php

// Open the file
$filename = 'pvemail.txt';
$fp = fopen($filename, 'r'); 

// Add each line to an array
if ($fp) {
   $array = explode("\n", fread($fp, filesize($filename)));
}
print_r ($array);
?>
```

I've managed to read the data and print each line out into an array, now all I need to do is make it look nice! Thanks a lot for your help guys!

Comment: Check your error logs! There'll be a detailed, more helpful error there somewhere.

Comment: can you put the error line

Comment: Server error

Reload  Less
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://eu12.euro.pec/~jlwx322/fread.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Error code: 500

Comment: also, where do i find the error logs? This isn't PHP throwing up the error its the web browser

Comment: Exactly, so figure out where your PHP error logs are. We don't know.

Comment: Isn't "$theData" already an array? Aren't your doing a print_r on it on the first part of your code? I mean: In the first part of your code you do that: print_r ($theData); .. So I suppose $theData is an array, isn't it? If so, I don't think you can use $my_array = explode("\n", $theData); on the array $theData. can you tell us more clearly what your $theData is? From the documentation, it should be a string. Are you sure that if it is a string you're correctly splitting it with the first explode? $my_array = explode("\n", $theData). can you please print_r($my_array)? Also.. SEMICOLONS!

Comment: There are inconsistencies in your code, the one line `explode` has "/n" whereas your main block has "\n".

Comment: the one line code was typed by hand so was a mistype on my part the full code was a copy and paste job. $theData is a string, also should have stated, the print_r $theData should have been commented out and wasn't being printed there, again my mistake.

Comment: <?php
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
  
  $myFile = "pvemail.txt";
  $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
  $theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
  $assoc_array = array();
  $my_array = explode("\n", $theData);
  foreach($my_array as $line)
  {
   $tmp = explode(" ", $line);
   $assoc_array[$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1];
  }
  fclose($fh);
  $mail = $assoc_array;
    ?>

this is my code now and I am getting another error

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /home/jlwx322/public_html/fread.php on line 14 Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /home/jlwx322/public_html/fread.php on line 14

relating to $assoc_array[$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Initial problems*

Looks like you have a few missing semicolons, unless you typed the reference code by hand and your actual code is correct.

`$assoc_array = array()`

`fclose($fh)`

---

*offset 1 does not exist*

`$tmp[1]` does not exist, which means some `$tmp` either had no values or only one value. It is most likely the case that one of the lines is a single word without a space or completely empty.

Comment: Ok, I turned on error reporting and fixed the syntax errors and I am now getting Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /home/jlwx322/public_html/fread.php on line 14 Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /home/jlwx322/public_html/fread.php on line 14 in relation to $assoc_array[$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1];

Comment: That means that `$tmp[1]` does not exist.

Comment: foreach($my_array as $line)
  {
   $tmp = explode(" ", $line);
   $assoc_array[$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1];
  }
This is my foreach loop where the $tmp variable is, is the error in the syntax? Sorry its a silly question I'm a complete novice

Comment: Suppose `$line` is `"broomstick"`. When you explode it, `$tmp` will hold an array of one value: `array("broomstick")`. When you try to access `$tmp[1]`, it does not exist.

Comment: ok, so could it be that my entire array has become one long string?

Comment: Maybe for one line, maybe for more. For easy debugging without any setup work, use var_dump() on a variable that you want to see, then reason through your code.